# PHP Exception not raised on fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I'm doing mysql queries with PHP5 and PDO.

I'm trying to handle exceptions from queries using try/catch. But if, for example, I have a syntax error like this :

```
try{
    $sql = 'IggggNSERT INTO t_table (ID, MONTH) VALUES (:ID, :MONTH)';
    $r = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $r->bindValue(':ID', $id);
    $r->bindValue(':MONTH', $month);
    $r->execute();
    return $r;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error');
}
```

I get this fatal error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object
```

But no exception is raised and my catch block is not executed.

How could I handle this so I could rollback previous queries?

Comment: Or generally, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but `die('Error');` is not exception handling by any means

Comment: @Your Common Sense : this die('Error') was just for illustration, so I don't put here the 60 lines of my real try/catch block...

Comment: Eeek! (Trying to gather my jaw from the floor) you have 60 lines of code in the catch block?!

Comment: :). Simply because I have a lot of columns to insert and a few things to do if anything went wrong. Anyway, if you can't understand that I won't put my whole project here just to ask one question, just down vote. I got my answer after all. If you told me that it could be confusing for others readers, I would understand but it seems obvious that handling an exception with die('Error') is not the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO will only throw an exception if the problem happens from within PDO. The error that you're getting is in reference to you accessing `$r->bindValue` despite $r failing to initialize.

In normal operation, you shouldn't ever get any syntax errors with your SQL.

You can however try setting the following line in your database file:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

As far as I understand from PHP.NET, prepare() throws an exception if this line is set, which should set off the `catch` statement.

> [PHP.NET PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
>
> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).